# Is it possible to get this text to line up horizontally in a table when only one column is using enumerate?

Tags: tables, enumerate

I would like to use a table for a heading column and a text column that would be a enumerated list. However, it seems like when I begin the list it automatically starts a new horizontal line for the \list text. Can this be aligned to the heading column text? Below is some code that I have tried and the compiled result...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.7in, top=0.7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{1in} p{5in} } 
 Top left cell & \begin{enumerate}[itemindent=-20pt]
     \item Is it possible to get this text to line up horizontally with the top left cell when using enumerate?
     \item Thank you!
 \end{enumerate} \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one method below in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE community!

One of possible solution is to enclose `enumerate` list in a `minipage`. This can be done by using `enumitem` package option `before` and `after`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{% this will have effect in each tabular
    \setlist[enumerate]{before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
                        after =\end{minipage}                   % <---
                        }   }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{1in} p{5in} }
 Top left cell & \begin{enumerate}
     \item Is it possible to get this text to line up horizontally with the top left cell when using enumerate?
     \item Thank you!
 \end{enumerate} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Alternative possibilities is extend column specification `p{...}` with minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{1in} >{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname}p{5in} } % <---
 Top left cell      & \begin{enumerate}
                 \item Is it possible to get this text to line up horizontally with the top left cell when using enumerate?
                 \item Thank you!
                    \end{enumerate} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

RCompilation result is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.7in, top=0.7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{1in} p{5in} } 
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]\item[] Top left cell\end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}[]
     \item Is it possible to get this text to line up horizontally with the top left cell when using enumerate?
     \item Thank you!
 \end{enumerate} \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```